# What kind of trucks explode when you run into them?

Tags: crossy-road

I was recently playing as Festive Chicken. I ran into a truck, and it blew a hole in the ground. I died, and the hole continued smoking.

[image]

What kind of truck does this?

Are there any other vehicles that do special things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the blue gasoline truck that smokes. I ran into one that was not smoking and it didn't explode.

Answer (score 3):

It's the blue garbage trucks that explode when you jump into them as you leap forward.

It turns out that you cannot cause the truck to explode by being run over, running into the truck head-on, nor jumping backwards into the top side of the truck. You must jump forward into the truck's visible side.

[image: blue transport or garbage truck]

Answer (score 0):

The blue garbage trucks blow up when you jump into them

I think it's because the garbage reacts with the gasoline and when something bumps it it blows up

Answer (score 0):

If you find a truck with a missile on it jump into it and it will blow up. Then you get a secret character named Michael boom.